# Spark SQL change format of the number

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

After `show` command spark prints the following:

```
+-----------------------+---------------------------+
|NameColumn             |NumberColumn               |
+-----------------------+---------------------------+
|name                   |4.3E-5                     |
+-----------------------+---------------------------+
```

Is there a way to change `NumberColumn` format to something like `0.000043`?

Answer (score 26):

you can use `format_number` [function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.format_number
df.withColumn("NumberColumn", format_number($"NumberColumn", 5))
```

here 5 is the decimal places you want to show

As you can see in the link above that the `format_number` functions returns a *string column*

> format_number(Column x, int d)
>   Formats numeric column x to a format like '#,###,###.##', rounded to d decimal places, and returns the result as a string column.

If your don't require `,` you can call `regexp_replace` function which is defined as

> regexp_replace(Column e, String pattern, String replacement)
>   Replace all substrings of the specified string value that match regexp with rep.

and use it as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_replace
df.withColumn("NumberColumn", regexp_replace(format_number($"NumberColumn", 5), ",", ""))
```

Thus *comma* (`,`) should be removed for large numbers.

Comment: But this replaces `NumberColumn` with `NumberColumn` string type. E.g. if I order by `NumberColumn` it will be ordered like string.

Comment: Yes @Cherry you are correct. You can cast it to Double as `df.withColumn("NumberColumn", format_number($"NumberColumn", 6).cast("Double"))` but doing so would just produce the original exponential value. So to show all the decimal values you will have to change the datatype to string.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `cast` operation as below:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(0.000043)).toDF("num")    

df.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
spark.sql("select CAST (num as DECIMAL(8,6)) from data")
```

adjust the precision and scale accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of pyspark you can use round() or bround() functions.
Theses functions return a numeric column and solve the problem with ",".

it would be like:

```
df.withColumn("NumberColumn", bround("NumberColumn",5))
```