# How to set display precision in PySpark Dataframe show

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do you set the display precision in PySpark when calling `.show()`?

Consider the following example:

```python
from math import sqrt
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

data = zip(
    map(lambda x: sqrt(x), range(100, 105)),
    map(lambda x: sqrt(x), range(200, 205))
)
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data, ["col1", "col2"])
df.select([f.avg(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()
```

Which outputs:

```python
#+------------------+------------------+
#|              col1|              col2|
#+------------------+------------------+
#|10.099262230352151|14.212583322380274|
#+------------------+------------------+
```

How can I change it so that it only displays 3 digits after the decimal point?

Desired output:

```python
#+------+------+
#|  col1|  col2|
#+------+------+
#|10.099|14.213|
#+------+------+
```

This is a PySpark version of [this scala question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007602/how-setup-spark-sql-show-to-output-different-number-format). I'm posting it here because I could not find an answer when searching for PySpark solutions, and I think it can be helpful to others in the future.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Round

The easiest option is to use [`pyspark.sql.functions.round()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.round):

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, round
df.select([round(avg(c), 3).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()
#+------+------+
#|  col1|  col2|
#+------+------+
#|10.099|14.213|
#+------+------+
```

This will maintain the values as numeric types.

#### Format Number

The [`functions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) are the same for *scala* and *python*. The only difference is the `import`.

You can use [`format_number`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#format_number(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20int)) to format a number to desired decimal places as stated in the official api document:

> Formats numeric column x to a format like '#,###,###.##', rounded to d decimal places, and returns the result as a string column.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, format_number 
df.select([format_number(avg(c), 3).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()
#+------+------+
#|  col1|  col2|
#+------+------+
#|10.099|14.213|
#+------+------+
```

The transformed columns would of `StringType` and a comma is used as a thousands separator:

```python
#+-----------+--------------+
#|       col1|          col2|
#+-----------+--------------+
#|500,100.000|50,489,590.000|
#+-----------+--------------+
```

As stated in the scala version of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45008775/5858851) we can use [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#regexp_replace(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to replace the `,` with any string you want

> Replace all substrings of the specified string value that match regexp with rep.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, format_number, regexp_replace
df.select(
    [regexp_replace(format_number(avg(c), 3), ",", "").alias(c) for c in df.columns]
).show()
#+----------+------------+
#|      col1|        col2|
#+----------+------------+
#|500100.000|50489590.000|
#+----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

just envelop the answer to a function witch only deal with float and double columns.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

def dataframe_format_float(df: DataFrame, num_decimals=4) -> DataFrame:
    r = []
    for c in df.dtypes:
        name, dtype = c[0], c[1]
        if dtype in ['float', 'double']:
            r.append(F.round(name, num_decimals).alias(name))
        else:
            r.append(name)
    df = df.select(r)
    return df
```