# How can I delimit a Float type column of a dataframe to have no more than 1 decimal in Pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, decimal, apache-spark-sql

I am working with a dataframe which has a column 'Col' of type Float. The values of the columns have too many decimals (example: 1.00000000000111). How can I limit the column to save values with only 1 decimal (example: 1.0)?

Comment: You can use the `round`, `ceil` or `floor` functions in `pyspark.sql.functions` ( depending on how you want to limit the digits)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set display precision in PySpark Dataframe show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48832493/how-to-set-display-precision-in-pyspark-dataframe-show)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use round from functions,

```
+----------------+
|             Col|
+----------------+
|1.00000000000111|
|     1.000000011|
+----------------+
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> df = df.withColumn('Col',F.round('Col',1))
>>> df.show()
+---+
|Col|
+---+
|1.0|
|1.0|
+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `round`, `ceil` or `floor` functions in `pyspark.sql.functions` ( depending on how you want to limit the digits)

For example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# assuming df is your dataframe and float_column_name is the name of the
# column with type FloatType, replace the column that has floats with 
# the column that has rounded floats:
df = df.withColumn('float_column_name', F.round('float_column_name', 2))
```

Answer (score -2):

Check this out:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([4.5678,5,1.00000000000111], columns=['Col'])
s = df['Col'].round(1)
print(s)

0       4.6
1       5.0
2       1.0
```

Comment: I don't have a pandas dataframe, I do have a Pyspark dataframe, so this solution does not work for me... Thanks anyway