# How to Set fraction upto 3 digits using Pyspark

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a column in my table for which I have to maintain fraction upto 3 digits using pyspark. If number of digits after decimal is more than 3, then round off the number upto 3 digits after decimal. If length of digits after decimal is less than 3, then append zeros. Below is an example.

Sample data:

[image]

Note that both "col_a" & "col_b" are string types.

Required Results:

[image]

How do I achieve it using pyspark?

Comment: hi, interesting, not sure if this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48832493/how-to-set-display-precision-in-pyspark-dataframe-show

Answer (score 2):

You can use `format_number` to get 3 decimal places, but it will give commas as thousand separators, so you can remove those using `regexp_replace`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('col_b', F.regexp_replace(F.format_number('col_b', 3), ',', ''))

df2.show()
+-----+------+
|col_a| col_b|
+-----+------+
|    A|10.000|
|    B|11.100|
|    C|12.340|
|    D|23.456|
|    E|34.568|
+-----+------+
```